# sed's regex for replacement

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I am creating the script which checks what is the user input and based on that this value is replaced in the file.

So far I have (but it does not work):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Type your domain: " domain
sed -i -e /\$put\_your\_domain =/ s/= .*/= ${domain}/ /list_of_domains
echo cat list_of_domains | grep '$put_your_domain'
```

Output:

```
./t.sh
Type your domain: GOV
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated address regex
```

As you can see I would like to replace the domain with whatever domain type. For example, we have:

```
$put_your_domain = JUS
```

And I want to replace it in the "list_of_domains" to `$put_your_domain = GOV`, and finally to echo it.

Comment: Try quotes round your sed command. Because you want variable substituion of $domain, they must be double quotes ""

Comment: Great, it works now, thank you. Do you know how am I not able to list it?
cat list_of_domains | grep '$put_your_domain' with above script.
When I type the same command in CLI it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ grep '$put_your_domain' list_of_domains
$put_your_domain = JUS

$ domain=GOV

$ sed -Ei 's/(\$put_your_domain = ).*/\1'"$domain"'/' list_of_domains

$ grep '$put_your_domain' list_of_domains
$put_your_domain = GOV
```

To learn about quotes in shell, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.